# Find the maximum integer such that this algebraic constraint is satisfied in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints, equation-solving

For example, I have an expression as a (arbitrary) function of integer `n`

```
f[n_]:=10^n*(n^2+4*n)
```

I want to find the maximum integer `n` such that `f[n]<=m` for another number `m`.

I could formulate this as an integer programming/optimization problem. But that complicates things. I could also just try starting from 1 and continue to test whether the constraint is violated. Is there any more efficient or elegant way of doing this? Please note also the constraint may allow an `Infinity` value of `n` and I ideally want to detect this situation.

Comment: If x is real, can one assume f[x] is a continuous function?

Comment: yes, you can assume f[x] is continuous.

Answer (score 5):

Depends. If you can settle for a heuristic result using numeric methods, that makes the assumption an integer max is the floor of a real max, then can do as below.

```
f[n_] := 10^n*(n^2 + 4*n)

In[32]:= Floor[First[NMaximize[{n, f[n] <= 10^8}, n]]]
Out[32]= 6
```

Daniel Lichtblau